# toggle conditional with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created nested checkboxes with psuedo(:before) icon and my toggle is not work correctly

where is my fold ? if u check it out you gonna see it's not going to work as expected

my html structure which is below

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>No Title</title>
</head>
<body> 

    <div class="new-checkbox">
    <ul>
      <li >
        <input type="checkbox" id="input1">
        <label for="input1">kategori <strong>(1)</strong>
        </label>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="input11">
            <label for="input11">kategori<strong>(11)</strong>
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="input12">
            <label for="input12">kategori <strong>(12)</strong>
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="input13">
            <label for="input13">kategori <strong>(13)</strong>
            </label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="input2">
        <label for="input2">kategori <strong>(2)</strong>
        </label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="input3">
        <label for="input3">kategori <strong>(3)</strong>
        </label>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="input31">
            <label for="input31">kategori <strong>(31)</strong>
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="input32">
            <label for="input32">kategori <strong>(32)</strong>
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="input33">
            <label for="input33">kategori <strong>(33)</strong>
            </label>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="input331">
                <label for="input331">kategori <strong>(331)</strong>
                </label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="input332">
                <label for="input332">kategori <strong>(332)</strong>
                </label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="input333">
                <label for="input333">kategori <strong>(333)</strong>
                </label>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- new checkbox-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.anitur.com.tr/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

my css structure

```
.new-checkbox ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 30px;
  font: normal 11px/16px"Segoe UI", Arial, Sans-serif;
}

.new-checkbox ul:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.new-checkbox ul li {
  margin: 3px 0;
}

.new-checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

.new-checkbox label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.new-checkbox input[type="checkbox"] + label:before {
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  content: "\00a0";
  display: inline-block;
  font: 16px/1em sans-serif;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 2px .25em 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: solid 1px #1375b3;
  color: #1375b3;
  opacity: .50;
}

.new-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
  background: #fff;
  color: #1375b3;
  content: "\2714";
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25) inset;
  opacity: 1;
}

.new-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  font-weight: bold;
}
/*
.new-checkbox ul li:before {
  content: "\25b6";
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  color: #e74c3c;
  font-size: 8px;
  line-height: 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
*/

.new-checkbox ul li:before {
  content:"";
  width:16px;
  height:16px;
  display:block;
  float:left;
  background:url("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_48px-16.png") no-repeat left center;
      margin-top: 2px;
}
 li.downCheck:before{
   content:"";
  width:16px;
  height:16px;
  display:block;
  float:left;
  background:url("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_48px-16.png") no-repeat left center !important;
    margin-top: 2px;
}
.new-checkbox li {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}


.new-checkbox input[type="checkbox"][id]:checked ~ li::before {
  content: "\25bc";
}

.new-checkbox li ul {
  display: none;
}

.new-checkbox li.has-checked > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

and my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {


  $('.new-checkbox input[type=checkbox]').on("change", function() {
    var checked = this.checked,
      $li = $(this).parent();
    $li.find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', checked).parent().toggleClass('has-checked', checked);

    $li.parentsUntil('.new-checkbox', 'li').each(function() {
      var $checks = $(this).find('ul input[type=checkbox]');
      $(this).children('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', !$checks.filter(':not(:checked)').length);

      $(this).toggleClass('has-checked', $checks.is(':checked'));
    });

  });

/*
  $('.new-checkbox li input[type="checkbox"]').on("click",function(e) {
        $(this).parent("li").toggleClass("downCheck");
    });
*/

    if($('.new-checkbox li:has("> ul")')) {
       $('.new-checkbox li input[type="checkbox"]').on("click",function(e) {
          $(this).parent("li").toggleClass("downCheck");
      });
    }

});
```

[and to see on codepen](http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/PNbZEB)

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "not working correctly"?

Comment: @TedA. if my li element hasn't ul child my toggle hasn't to be toggle

Comment: I mean..if u click kategori2 you gonna see..my kategori2 has no ul that is why my toggle is working broken